# "[(),()]" array in Haskell

Tags: haskell, automated-tests, quickcheck

Recently, I've been doing automatic testing with Haskell and QuickCheck. Some time I have got some fails, but the program retrieved `[(),()]` as checked argument.

**What does `"[(),()]"` mean?**

Comment: A list of two *units*.

Comment: Meaning depends on the observer.

Answer (score 6):

That's a list of two `()` (or "unit") values.

```
Prelude> :t [(),()]
[(),()] :: [()]
Prelude> :info ()
data () = ()    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Tuple’
```

A list is not an array; an array is flat, with constant-time indexing. A list is a nested recursive type.